# Relationship between quotient of sum of exponentials and uniform distributions

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

Let $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ be iid with $P(X>t)=e^{-t}$ for $t>0$.
Let $U$, $V$ be independent uniform on $[0,1]$. Let $A=\min(U,V)$ and $B=\max(U,V)$. Show that $(A,B),$ and $(X/(X+Y+Z), (X+Y)/(X+Y+Z))$ have the same joint distribution.

So, the joint distribution for A and B should be:

$f_{A,B}(a,b)=f_{A|B}(a|b)f_B(b)=f_{B|A}(b|a)f_a(a).$ (*)

$f_{A|B}(a|b)=I_{[0,B]}/B$,
$f_{B|A}(b|a)=I_{[a,1]}/(1-a)$,
$f_{a}(a)=f_{b}(b)=I_{[0,1]}$.

However, using these, the equality above (*) does not hold.  Where is the mistake here?

Comment: You should add what you have tried. It helps people trying to answer get "straight to the point", rather than spelling out things that you are already aware of.

Comment: though this won't exactly answer your question it may give you some idea of what direction to head in (Note X,Y and Z are $Exp(1)$): http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/894506/let-x-and-y-be-independent-exponentially-distributed-with-mean-1-show-df